# Custom label using vue and element UI library radio buttons

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I'm using Element UI radio buttons on a form and am trying to create a custom label for each selection. on each radio button there is a prop "label" where I can add my label text which works fine. The issue is I need to have a different style on half of the label text. is this possible?

for instance: `label="Morning (9 AM - 12 PM)"` I would like to be able to target the time and
style different from "Morning". something like `label="Morning <span>(9 AM - 12 PM)</span>"`

```js
    <el-form-item
                prop="selfBestTimeToContact"
                class="form-item--radio form-item--radio--radio-adjacent"
                :show-message="false"
              >
                <el-radio-group
                  v-model="formData.selfBestTimeToContact"
                  ref="selfBestTimeToContact"
                >
                  <ol>
                    <li class="radio-list-item">
                      <el-radio
                        id="selfBestTimeToContactMorning"
                        label="Morning (9 AM - 12 PM)"
                        name="selfBestTimeToContact"
                        class="radio--bold"
                      />
                      <p>Test</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="radio-list-item">
                      <el-radio
                        id="selfBestTimeToContactAfternoon"
                        label="Afternoon (12 PM - 5 PM)"
                        name="selfBestTimeToContact"
                        class="radio--bold"
                      />
                    </li>

                    <li class="radio-list-item">
                      <el-radio
                        id="selfBestTimeToContactEvening"
                        label="Evening (5 PM - 8 PM)"
                        name="selfBestTimeToContact"
                        class="radio--bold radio-label"
                      />
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                </el-radio-group>
              </el-form-item>
```

Comment: what is stopping you from using `label="Morning <span>(9 AM - 12 PM)</span>"` ?

Comment: The span will get rendered as text and not a span element

Comment: seems like you need to use `v-html` somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If given, the default slot of `el-radio` is used as the displayed label (while the `label` attribute would be used as the value), so you could just put your label with markup inside, including the class on the span of text to style:

```html
<template>
  <el-radio>Morning <span class="time">(9 AM - 12 PM)</span></el-radio>
</template>

<style>
.time {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YzZKjry)